# PostgreSQL - PUBLICATION tries to copy the data which already exists in another database?

Tags: postgresql, replication, master-slave-replication, postgresql-11

I have database and table collection_city on one server. It has 21 rows.
I have database and table collection_city on second server. It also has 21 rows.

They both have this row:

```
tinker=# table collection_city;
 id |     name      |    alias     | postal_code | region_id 
----+---------------+--------------+-------------+-----------
  2 | Obrenovac     | obrenovac    |             |         1
```

id column is the primary key.

I created Publication on first server:

```
CREATE PUBLICATION tinkerpub FOR ALL TABLES;

tinker=# \dRp[+]
                      Publication tinkerpub
  Owner   | All tables | Inserts | Updates | Deletes | Truncates 
----------+------------+---------+---------+---------+-----------
 postgres | t          | t       | t       | t       | t
(1 row)
```

I created Subscription on second server:

```
CREATE SUBSCRIPTION tinkersub CONNECTION 'dbname=tinker host=192.168.150.5 user=postgres password=test port=5432' PUBLICATION tinkerpub;
```

But I see errors like this (it is trying to copy the row with id 2 AGAIN???):

```
2019-06-25 15:51:37.178 CEST [2270] ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "collection_city_pkey"
2019-06-25 15:51:37.178 CEST [2270] DETAIL:  Key (id)=(2) already exists.
2019-06-25 15:51:37.178 CEST [2270] CONTEXT:  COPY collection_city, line 1
2019-06-25 15:51:37.181 CEST [21905] LOG:  background worker "logical replication worker" (PID 2270) exited with exit code 1
```

Why system is trying to copy the data which already exists with exactly the same data?
I see errors for all tables.
How we can resolve this? Does the second table should be totally empty before the subscription process? But it does not have any sense...why I should not have both tables populated and then to start the process of replication at one moment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `CREATE SUBSCRIPTION` will first copy all the existing data from the source tables. The idea is that you usually start with an empty destination database created with something like `pg_restore -s`.

If you don't want to have the initial data copy, create the subscription like this:

```
CREATE SUBSCRIPTION ...
WITH (copy_data = false);
```

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsubscription.html) for details.

Comment: Hi, thanks for info - does this mean that every new data after the subscription is created will be copied? Basically I am populating two tables with Django framework so they both have the data.... after they are populated I would like to copy from publication.. so is it OK now to first DROP the SUBSCRIPTION and then to CREATE it with this new parameter? thanks

Comment: I don't follow. Of course all data modifications will be replicated once the subscription is created. That's the point of replication, isn't it?

Comment: Because I already created SUBSCRIPTION should I DROP it and recreate it? Do I need to somehow remove replication slot which is created also before I create SUBSCRIPTION again?

Comment: You can either drop the replication slot again or create a new subscription that uses an existing replication slot.